# .NET Assembly Long File Name Causes DLL To Produce Different Results

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have been stumped on a problem with an assembly written in C# targeting .NET 4.5 framework. The assembly references a DLL that provides DirectShow related video capture devices to preview video. Tested with Decklink video capture cards, Logitech 9000 webcam, FaceTime webcam, and 2 Logitech C920 webcams.

In one project all webcams work. In variant projects, the 2 Logitech C920 webcams fail to work.

I have finally figured out that its the amount of characters in the assembly file name that is causing it not to work, and now I'm asking myself, WHY?

If the assembly name is 8 characters or less, the Logitech C920 works. If the assembly name is longer than 8 characters (not including .exe), it doesn't. Weird!

The file system in question is NTFS, 8 characters lengths on file names was a restriction of FAT... so how is this happening and why?

Comment: I hardly can believe, that the assembly-name is the problem. This would mean, not a single on of the built in .net Assemblys would load. It would help, if you'd show us some errors/exceptions

Comment: I can hardly believe either. Literally changing the name to something shorter after it's been compiled does cause different results. There are no exceptions except that I put MessageBox's in on the routines being called from the referenced library. The result returns True however the event that logs from the DLL does not log anything when the name is greater then 8 characters. And the webcam is supposed to light up when active, in which case it does not when greater then 8.

Comment: I dug in deeper of the DLL which is obfuscated but it makes reference to DataStead and looks like it is merely a wrapper that calls identical routines that DataStead need to handle DirectShow calls.

Comment: What is your Targetplatform and what is the 3rd-Party's? x86 or Any or x64?

Comment: 100% 64 bit, .NET Framework 4.5. Happens on both Windows 7 Embedded and Windows 10 Professional. I understand that it may sound like a dumb question and that it doesn't make any sense at which point I'm willing to show someone this using TeamViewer as it is baffling me.

Comment: 3rd party DLL is AVSpeed iconf library.

Comment: Does one of these [Samples](https://github.com/avspeed/iConf.NET-SDK-Demos) work?

Comment: WPFDemo does, up until I add 2 characters to the name. Also, it only causes the Logitech C920 to not function... little harder to test for anyone else.

Comment: I found in the demo nothing like name.. What *name* do you mean?

Comment: I just realized those samples were 4 years old, here's directly from their Site http://avspeed.com/storage/iconfnet/demos/SDKDemos.zip 
WPFDemo project should be at the bottom.

Comment: Maybe im done with this day, but looked into that sources and there's nothing done with a name. Except the `VideoPreviewStarted`-Method. But also there, the `deviceName` isnt used. Can please post the corresponding code, with this *name*-thingy?

Comment: The file name... build the project and rename the exe to something greater then 8 characters not including .exe so WPFDemo12.exe. With a C920 camera, no worky.

Comment: New information, only WPF apps are affected. Windows Forms doesn't have an issue.